# Binding custom data type transmit null to converter

Tags: kotlin, jooq

I'm using Jooq and Kotlin in my project. I have object EventEnvelope in which field of type Event is composed. I want to store this field as JSON in my DB (postgres). I prepared jooq custom datatype bindings and converter as it is described here -> https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.10/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/ 
Below I paste converter, binding and gradle generator code.

My questions are:

1. Is it ok to use kotlin non null types with jooq bindings?
2. Is this configuration ok? What should I change?
3. When I want to store value my converter gets null in from func. I don't why is that.

I am out of ideas what should I do to fix it.

```
class JSONEventConverter constructor(
    private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper,
    private val schemaMatcher: SchemaMatcher
) : Converter<Any, Event> {
    override fun from(databaseObject: Any): Event {
        return schemaMatcher.parse(databaseObject.toString())
    }

    override fun to(userObject: Event): Any {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(userObject)
    }

    override fun fromType(): Class<Any> {
        return Any::class.java
    }

    override fun toType(): Class<Event> {
        return Event::class.java
    }

    companion object {
        fun create(): JSONEventConverter {
            return JSONEventConverter(jacksonObjectMapper(), 
                SchemaMatcher.create())
        }
    }
}

class PostgresJSONEventBinding : Binding<Any, Event> {
    override fun register(ctx: BindingRegisterContext<Event>?) {
        ctx!!.statement().registerOutParameter(ctx.index(), Types.VARCHAR)
    }

    override fun sql(ctx: BindingSQLContext<Event>?) {
        ctx!!.render().visit(DSL.`val`(ctx.convert(converter())
            .value())).sql("::json")
    }

    override fun converter(): Converter<Any, Event> {
        return JSONEventConverter.create()
    }

    override fun get(ctx: BindingGetResultSetContext<Event>?) {     
        ctx!!.convert(converter())
            .value(ctx.resultSet().getString(ctx.index()))
    }

    override fun get(ctx: BindingGetStatementContext<Event>?) {
        ctx!!.convert(converter())
            .value(ctx.statement().getString(ctx.index()))
    }

    override fun get(ctx: BindingGetSQLInputContext<Event>?) {
        throw SQLFeatureNotSupportedException()
    }

    override fun set(ctx: BindingSetStatementContext<Event>?) {
        ctx!!.statement().setString(ctx.index(), 
            Objects.toString(ctx.convert(converter()).value(), null))
    }

    override fun set(ctx: BindingSetSQLOutputContext<Event>?) {
        throw SQLFeatureNotSupportedException()
    }
}

generator {
    name = 'org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator'
    strategy {
        name = 'org.jooq.util.DefaultGeneratorStrategy'
    }
    database {
        name = 'org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresDatabase'
        schemata {
            schema {
                inputSchema = someSchema
            }
            schema {
                inputSchema = otherSchema
            }
        }
        forcedTypes {
            forcedType {
                userType = 'package.Event'
                binding = 'package.PostgresJSONEventBinding'
                expression = 'someSchema\\.event_store\\.event'
            }
        }
    }
    generate {
        relations = true
        deprecated = false
        records = true
        immutablePojos = true
        fluentSetters = true
    }
    target {
        packageName = appName
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question mixes 3 questions in one. It's a bit difficult to know what you're really after, here. What *exactly* is the problem you're running into? Try focusing your question on that problem. It will be much easier to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so in my case it was about java-kotlin interoperability between nullable types in Java and non-null types in kotlin. All I had to do was implementing converter using nullable types in kotlin (the ones with `?`).

Correct converter look like this:

```
class JSONEventConverter constructor(
    private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper,
    private val schemaMatcher: SchemaMatcher
) : Converter<Any, Event> {
    override fun from(databaseObject: Any?): Event? {
        return databaseObject?.let { schemaMatcher.parse(it.toString()) }
    }

    override fun to(userObject: Event?): Any? {
        return userObject?.let { objectMapper.writeValueAsString(it) }
    }

    override fun fromType(): Class<Any> {
        return Any::class.java
    }

    override fun toType(): Class<Event> {
        return Event::class.java
    }

    companion object {
        fun create(): JSONEventConverter {
            return JSONEventConverter(serializingObjectMapper(),         
                SchemaMatcher.create())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is it ok to use kotlin non null types with jooq bindings?

jOOQ (or any Java library) will not respect your Kotlin non-nullable guarantees and might produce null values where you wouldn't expect them. So, perhaps it's not a good idea after all.

At the interface between jOOQ and your code, you must ensure yourself that this cannot happen.

> Is this configuration ok? What should I change?

That's an open ended question. If you have any specific questions, please ask.

> When I want to store value my converter gets null in from func. I don't why is that.

There are not enough infos in your question to help you about this

Comment: thank you for your answer (as always). I was thinking about my problem again in order to precise my question and I solved it. Thanks for inspiring answer. As this question is useless should I remove it?

Comment: @Piotrowy: No, don't remove it. Answer it yourself! :-) Someone else might still find it useful...